# Redirect the link /id to the new domain and exclude the remaining in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a file upload website. Uploaded files will be in the form of domain.com/id. For example:

domain.com/348D945e

domain.com/5W483d7c
.....

I want to redirect all this type of id link to the new domain: newdomain.com/id and exclude the remaining page redirects. For example

domain.com/login.html

domain.com/account.html

domain.com/admin.php

Leave the link with the .html, php, css, js extension intact.
And the important thing is that when I login to the account in domain.com and I access the redirected link newdomain.com/id still retains my login status. Which solution to rewrite the link on nginx helps me solve this problem?

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?_page_url=$1 last; }
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }    
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?_page_url=$1 last;
        }
    }      
    location /files/ {
        root /home/domain.com/public_html;
        post_action @afterdownload;
        internal;
    }    
    # these locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location /core/logs/ {
        deny all;
    }    
    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }
```

Comment: You could use `rewrite ^(/[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ http://newdomain.com$1 permanent;`

Comment: it works. But I log in at domain.com, the newdomain.com/id redirected link will lose the login status. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+ {
    proxy_pass newdomain.com/$request_uri
}
```

Comment: help me id contain both alphanumeric? The above code lacks a mark ;

Comment: I have replaced it. location ~ ^/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+/  but it does not redirect. domain.com/623AA5FE000D